# Get id of clicked link in and pass it to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a class = "link" href="#" id = "one">
<div class="secret_div" id = "secret_one" style = "display: none;">
    <p>This is a secret</p>
</div>


<a class = "link" href="#" id = "two" style = "display: none;">
<div class="secret_div" id = "secret_two">
    <p>This is a 2nd secret</p>
</div>
```

How do you get the id of the linked that's clicked?
this is the JQuery script  that I used but doesn't seem to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".link").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var element = ".secret_" + id + "#" + "id";
        $(element).show();
    }
        )
});
</script>
```

Im trying to concatenate `".secret_two#two"` with the selected link's `id` so I can and store it into an `element` variable so then I could do something like this
`$(element).show()`

how do we go about doing this

Comment: use `var element = ".secret_" + id;`

Comment: Your method looks ok, but never use hashes `#` in id's and classes. Also, you need to tell jQuery if `element` is a classname or id...

Comment: However, no impact on your functionality but one suggestion: always close tags in html, you should close `a` tags in your code.

Comment: @RubyRacer yes that's what Im trying to figure out. im trying to do this `$(secret_two#two)` im confused as to how to concatenate the strings so it'll look like that

Comment: Can you please post proper Question at first? You change the question time to time and then we have to rethink and modify the answers. It wastes time of both the parties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var element = "#secret_" + id;
```

instead of

```
var element = ".secret_#" + id;
```

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".link").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var element = "#secret_" + id;
        $(element).show();
    }
        )
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why use `.secret_` ? Please read his question . And check this `<a class = "link" href="#" id = "two" style = "display: none;">
<div class="secret_div" id = "secret_two">`. This is his structure. He is using ID such as secret_two and not Class.

Answer (score 2):

However, Solutions provided by other contributors looks fine, but here is an alternative:

```
$(function(){
  $('.link').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.secret_div').show(); //<-- No need to work on ID
  });    
});
```

And if many `DIV` elements inside `a.link`, then use `:first` in selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
$(".link").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var element = ".secret_" + id;
    $(element).show();
}
    )
 });
```

and use secret_ `remove`#`after`secret_`

Comment: Why use `.secret_` ? Please read his question . And check this `<a class = "link" href="#" id = "two" style = "display: none;">
<div class="secret_div" id = "secret_two">`. This is his structure. He is using ID such as secret_two and not Class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".link").click(function(e){
    var idClicked = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#secret_" + idClicked).show();
});
```

Use it. And no need of element var.